# Micronaut @Controller wildcard

Tags: micronaut

I'm using micronaut 2.0 with Kotlin and would like to creating something like the following:

```kotlin
@Controller("/foo/*/api/v1")
class MyController {
    @Get("/data")
    fun data(): String {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I would like is for this controller to match `/foo/bar/api/v1/data` as well as `/foo/baz/api/v1/data`. As far as I can tell, the controller URI does not take a wildcard. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, you just put a variable in the `@Controller` path, like this:

```kotlin
@Controller("/foo/{someVar}/api/v1")
class MyController {
    @Get("/data")
    fun data(): String {
        ...
    }
}
```